# Dropdown list in Razor for array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a dropdownlist in Razor and the Razor code looks like this:

```
@for (int l = 0; l < Model.Entries.Count; l++)
{
    @Model.Entries[l].StatusId
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Entries[l].StatusId, Model.DropDownItems)
}
```

But output only becomes

```
1003
<select id="Entries_0__StatusId" name="Entries[0].StatusId">
    <option value="1001">1001 option 1</option>
    <option value="1002">1002 option 2</option>
    <option value="1003">1003 option 3</option>
</select> 
1002
<select id="Entries_1__StatusId" name="Entries[1].StatusId">
    <option value="1001">1001 option 1</option>
    <option value="1002">1002 option 2</option>
    <option value="1003">1003 option 3</option>
</select>
```

E.g. the 1003 value should also have made option 1003 selected, **but nothing is selected**.

My model is just a simpel array and also contains all values for the dropdownlist.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<MyModelEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelEntry
{
    public string StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

and the populations is also trivial.

```
public ActionResult Get(int Id)
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.DropDownItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1001", Text = "1001 option 1" }, 
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1002", Text = "1002 option 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1003", Text = "1003 option 3" }
    };

    model.Entries = new List<MyModelEntry>()
    {
        new MyModelEntry { StatusId = "1003" },
        new MyModelEntry { StatusId = "1002" }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong. I am not very good at Razor so all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: new SelectListItem { Value = "1003", Text = "1003 option 3" , Selected = true}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you can use `SelectList`:

```
@for (int l = 0; l < Model.Entries.Count; l++)
{
    @Model.Entries[l].StatusId
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Entries[l].StatusId, 
                          new SelectList(Model.DropDownItems, "Value", "Text", Model.Entries[l].StatusId))
}
```